# Webpages in Android Browsers - Image dimensions

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I have a 1513x1079 image which resizes great when I resize my desktop browser.
However, when I open the same webpage on my android phone, everything shows up great, except the image. The whole page resizes properly, but there is no picture. There is only a tiny picture icon in the upper left corner.

Is there some upper limit to image dimensions for phones?
If so, why is there such a limit?
Does image responsiveness have some sort of dimension limit?

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1"/>
        <title>Projects web page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="jQuery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>



    <body>
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-6" id = "picture">
                    <img src="R1lr_cut.jpg" alt = "R1 Engine" class = "responsive"/>
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-6" id = "home_text">
                    <h1>Inline 4 Engines</h1>
                    <ul id = "links">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calculate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div id = "filler_text">
                        <h4>Historic information</h4>
                        <p>
                            The first across-the-frame 4-cylinder motorcycle was the 1939 racer Gilera 500 Rondine, it also had double-over-head camshafts, forced-inducting supercharger and was liquid-cooled.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Modern inline-four motorcycle engines first became popular with Honda's SOHC CB750 introduced in 1969, and others followed in the 1970s. 
                            Since then, the inline-four has become one of the most common engine configurations in street bikes. 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Outside of the cruiser category, the inline-four is the most common configuration because of its relatively high performance-to-cost ratio.
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            The success of the Honda CB750 and the Kawasaki Z1 got the attention of the Germans over at BMW. The Honda especially had been an industry game changer. 
                            BMW’s motorcycle engine at that time was a horizontally opposed “boxer” twin cylinder engine that the company had settled on when they reverse engineered a British Douglas motorcycle with a boxer engine mounted longitudinally in the frame at the end of the First World War.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code :

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    }

.responsive {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    }


#picture {
    padding-right: -10%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    width: 100%;
    }

#links li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
    /*outline : 1px solid yellow;*/
    width: 14%;
    margin-right: 11%;
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    }

#links{
    /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0.5%;
    }


a {
    /*outline :1px solid green;*/
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
    color: #666666;
    }

a:hover {
    background-color:  #333333;
    color:#66ccff;
    }

#home_text {
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 8%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 0%;
    }

#home_text h1 {
    margin-left: 5%;
    /*outline: 1px solid purple*/
    }

#filler_text {
    padding-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    }
```

Comment: How is the image added? html? css? and what styles are applied to it...

Comment: Hi, image is added through HTML. Only right and top padding are applied to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image size is set in percents, not in pixels or anything else.
Example:

```
<img src="yourimage.png">
<style>
img{width: 100%; /*100 can be any, but will fit 100% of the block*/}
</style>
```

Comment: Width is set in percent, just double checked.

Comment: And make sure the image is present in the directory if you do kinda mobile redirect. It must be there or do /image.png in src attribute

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: @Apollo this may be because of bootstrap try making it a div background as in answer below. If didn’t help don’t use bootstrap

Comment: Tried, but it isn't responsive, the image disappears after resizing browser.I kind of want to use bootstrap just because it simplifies employing responsive design. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @Apollo you got a mistake, there mustn’t be any slash at the and of img tag

Comment: Damn, didn't catch that, thanks. Despite the change, it still isn't working.

Comment: You have same mistakes in <head> tags

Comment: @Apollo and try adding height to image

Comment: Do you mean meta tags? If so, isn't closing tags an option?

Comment: @Apollo in link tag

Comment: Damn, again... Thanks, but still no change.

Comment: @Apollo did have you set height?

Comment: Yup. There's got to be some css code colliding. I'm kind of lost what to do anymore.

Comment: Yeah, can't find anything wrong or any warnings. Ah, forget it man, many thanks for your help. I'll figure it out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your image a block background: `

## myimg{background-image: url(“pic.jpg”); background-size: cover;}

`Sorry if syntax is wrong, just typing from my phone. Also you can try doing like this instead of making it a block:`


img{display: inline-block;}
`
If this doesn’t help change inline-block to block.